# Eigenvalues of $4\times 4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I have spent an hour and a half on this problem, just cannot solve for eigenvalues of this $4\times 4$ matrix $A$. Any help will be appreciated.

\begin{bmatrix}
7 & 1 & 2& 2\\
1&4&-1&-1\\
-2&1&5&-1\\
1 &1&2 &8
\end{bmatrix}

I get $\det(A-\lambda I)$ is equivalent to the determinant of

$$\begin{bmatrix}
7-\lambda & 1 & 2& 2\\
0&9-2\lambda&3-\lambda&-3\\
-2&1&5-\lambda&-1\\
0 &3&9-\lambda &15-2\lambda
\end{bmatrix}.$$

And then, everything is super messy. I even did not get an integer at the end.

Comment: Are you certain that you want to try row reduction before calculating the determinant? Can't you just calculate the determinant directly?

Comment: @Arthur I tried. It was even worse. By row reduction, I got several 0's, which made my life easier.

Comment: You may use `A = [7 1 2 2; 1 4 -1 -1; -2 1 5 -1; 1 1 2 8];` and `[v,l] = eig(A);` to check your work at [Octave Online](//octave-online.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you would expect to need some luck to find the eigenvalues of a $4\times 4$-matrix by hand. Here, there are some similar elements in the upper right hand corner of $A$. By subtracting the third column from the fourth column, we get that
$$\det(A-\lambda I)=\begin{vmatrix} 7-\lambda & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 4-\lambda & -1 & -1 \\ -2 & 1 & 5-\lambda & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 & 8-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 7-\lambda & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 4-\lambda & -1 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 & 5-\lambda & \lambda-6 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 & 6-\lambda\end{vmatrix}$$
Add the fourth row to the third row, and expand by the last column:
$$\det(A-\lambda I)=(6-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix} 7-\lambda & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 4-\lambda & -1 \\ -1 & 2 & 7-\lambda \end{vmatrix}$$
Add the second row to the third row:
$$\det(A-\lambda I)=(6-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix} 7-\lambda & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 4-\lambda & -1 \\ 0 & 6-\lambda & 6-\lambda \end{vmatrix}=(6-\lambda)^2\begin{vmatrix} 7-\lambda & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 4-\lambda & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{vmatrix}$$
Subtract the third row twice from the first row, and add the third row to the second row, before you expand by the last column: 
$$\det(A-\lambda I)=(6-\lambda)^2\begin{vmatrix}7-\lambda & -1 \\ 1 & 5-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=(6-\lambda)^4$$